# webjar requirejs angular ie8 foreach loop

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, requirejs, webjars

I cannot make requirejs work with angularjs project and webjars in ie8, ( I dont have error in firefox, chrome).

With ie debug bar I have this error :

```
Object doesn't support property or method
```

In this code :

```
webjarsAngularjsChildren.forEach(function(child) {    
webjarsAngularjsPaths[child] = webjars.path("angularjs", child);
webjarsAngularjsShim[child] = ["angular", "webjars!angular.js"];
});
```

this code is generate with requirejs/webjars

forEach loop is compatible with IE 8 ?

how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: Try a newer version of the Angular WebJar and a newer version of the `webjars-locator` library to void this.

Comment: How to set version of webjars-locator ? I use the last versoion in Angular WebJar : 1.3.0-beta.2

Comment: Depends on what your build tool is.  The docs might help: http://www.webjars.org/documentation

Comment: I use  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" %2.2.0, with play  2.2.0

Comment: Add: "org.webjars" % "webjars-locator" % "0.14"

Comment: I have many errors when I add webjars-locator : The webjars plugin loader (e.g. webjars!angular-ui) has been deprecated. The RequireJS config in the angular-ui WebJar may need to be updated. Please file an issue

Comment: Those are just warnings.  But you should check if newer versions of your WebJars have the new RequireJS support.  If not you can file issues on the WebJars.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is described here : 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5201

I had the same problemusing IE8 in emulation mode on IE11. I installed a VM running Windows XP and a real IE8 and had no problem.

Comment: I have error in real IE8 in windows Xp environnemet

Comment: I have this error in webjarsAngularjsChildren.forEach line : Message : Cet objet ne gère pas cette propriété ou cette méthode
Ligne : 262
Caractère : 1

Comment: Well if you are using the real IE8, I have no clue. In angular.js inside the forEach method, a trick is explicitly specified for IE8